# making iOS app having option to enable and disable sound

Tags: iphone, ios

i want to make iOS app with play sound on every button tap, and i can disable/Enable sound from setting screen. Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, try this code

In your setting screen .h file

```
@interface SettingScreen : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate,AVAudioSessionDelegate>
{
    AVAudioPlayer *audioplayer;
}
```

in .m file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString* BS_path_blue=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Click" ofType:@"mp3"];
    audioplayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:BS_path_blue]  error:NULL];
    audioplayer.delegate=self;
    [audioplayer prepareToPlay];

    UISwitch *soundsOnOffButton = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 8, 130, 27)];
    [self.view addSubview:soundsOnOffButton];
    [soundsOnOffButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     soundsOnOffButton.on = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"sound"];
}

-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (soundsOnOffButton.on)
    {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"sound"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"sound"]==YES)
        {
            [audioplayer play];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"sound"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

this is for setting screen. Now if you want to play a sound for any button in another screen , add delegate and frist four line to your that file then add this line to their action.

```
-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"sound"]==YES)
    {
         [audioplayer play];
     }

    // other code
}
```

Revert me if any problem.

Comment: thanks for answering it might work but do i have to check it for every button click? there is no generic approach of doing this so that when i set audio ON it play and when i turn it OFF dont play...

Comment: This will works great. Accept it as right answer if it solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the setting before playing any sound..?

```
// pseudo code
- (void)playSound:(NSInteger)soundID;
{
  if(settings.soundEnabled) {
    [SoundPlayer playSoundWithID:soundID];
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer, so do i have to check it on every button click? there is no better approach of doing this?

Comment: What do you think how this works internally, if there was a setting like this? Someone needs to check the settings. Just use the same method to play a sound everywhere and within that method check your setting.

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the Device sound(app will be rejected) how ever you can set volume By assigning some values between 0 to 1 .in your setting option if user selects disable then set it to 0. 
check sam's answer here : [How to disable iOS System Sounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284402/how-to-disable-ios-system-sounds/)

Comment: well in that case, volume set will be for whole phone or only for my app?