# AVSystemController to disable iOS System sounds gives not found for architecture i386 error

Tags: ios, architecture, avsystemcontroller

I want to silent the ringer volume.
So I am using this link to do that - [How to disable iOS System Sounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284402/how-to-disable-ios-system-sounds)
But if I use the code:

```
- (void) setSystemVolumeLevelTo:(float)newVolumeLevel
{
    Class avSystemControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVSystemController");
    id avSystemControllerInstance = [avSystemControllerClass performSelector:@selector(sharedAVSystemController)];

NSString *soundCategory = @"Ringtone";

NSInvocation *volumeInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                                  [avSystemControllerClass instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:
                                   @selector(setVolumeTo:forCategory:)]];
[volumeInvocation setTarget:avSystemControllerInstance];
[volumeInvocation setSelector:@selector(setVolumeTo:forCategory:)];
[volumeInvocation setArgument:&newVolumeLevel atIndex:2];
[volumeInvocation setArgument:&soundCategory atIndex:3];
[volumeInvocation invoke];
```

}

It crashes on

```
NSInvocation *volumeInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                                  [avSystemControllerClass instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:
                                   @selector(setVolumeTo:forCategory:)]];
```

because the value returned is nil.

and If I import the framework etc and then use this code

```
[[AVSystemController sharedAVSystemController] setVolumeTo:0.0 forCategory:@"Ringtone"];
```

It does not run giving me the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVSystemController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in SettingsViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Someone please guide me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to add following lines in you first method. As you are using a private framework(Celestial) so you have to import it on runtime.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework"];
BOOL success = [bundle load];
```