# iOS: How to set ringer and alert volume within my App

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, mute

For my APP, one of the important function is to mute the iPhone, but I can't find any available iOS API that I can use to mute the phone(or change the ringer volume level to minimum). Is their a specific API for developer to mute (or change the ringer volume of) the phone, if their is not, is there a indirect way to do this?

Comment: Any luck in solving this problem?

Comment: No... I kind of stop finding the answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only mute other application sounds. You need to configure the AVAudioSession category :

AVAudioSession Class Reference : http://goo.gl/rh7CX7 .

Look for which fit the most for your application. You only need to set it once in your code (make sure it's called).

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient, error: nil) // AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient is default AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

Applications developed using the official SDK cannot change (and in most cases cannot even access) system-wide settings.

It is possible, but only using private API's. I only went as far as muting the ringer, but you should be able to control the master level as well.

See [How to disable iOS System Sounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284402/how-to-disable-ios-system-sounds/)

Comment: You can try this also if it works for you 
float value = 0.0f;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume, sizeof(float), &value);

value = 10 for full volume and 0 for mute