# Mute sound in Xamarin.iOS (iOS version >11)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, audio, xamarin.ios

I am using [`XamarinMediaManager`](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager) (built using `MPMusicPlayerController`) to Build an audio player for iOS, i am looking for a way to mute the sound on a button click, this works perfectly on iOS 9:

```
MPMusicPlayerController.ApplicationMusicPlayer.Volume = 0
```

But it looks like it is deprecated on newer versions: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/1624567-volume

How to achieve the same thing using another way? (i am not looking to build an entire volume manager, i just want to set the volume).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation posted it's been deprecated for `MPVolumeView`, which is their new slider view for adjusting audio output. I know you're not looking to add the slider to your UI and want to do it programmatically, which based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218729/ios-7-mpmusicplayercontroller-volume-deprecated-how-to-change-device-volume-no?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) you can still technically do it. Although, it does feel kind of hacky.

Here is the C# equivalent:

```
UISlider slider = null;
var volumeView = new MPVolumeView();
foreach (var view in volumeView.Subviews)
{
    if (view is UISlider)
    {
        slider = (UISlider)view;
        break;
    }
}

slider.Value = 0;
```

It's worth noting I'm unsure whether if this will actually effect how `XamarinMediaManager` is playing the audio.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try it out when i get access to the iOS11 device

Comment: Unfortunately, i couldn't get this to work on iOS 11 ://

Comment: In that case, you may have to write your own instead of using `XamarinMediaManager`